# How to animate a soft object while it is squashed on the floor? without squash rigid meshes attached on?

Tags: animation

I need to animate a rotating soft object while it is squashed on the floor following the wavy shape of the floor.

Thanks to a contributor on this site I partially solved my problem.

Now I don't know how to avoid squashing of a rigid object attached under my soft mesh (which is affected by the lattice distortion).
These rigid objects should remain solid, the lattice modifier should not affect this rigid objects.
Rigid objects should only be rotated following the movement of the soft object.

Like in this video https://youtu.be/cUsXyimUw6o?t=69 from 1:09 to 1:17

How I can do this?

Thanks
[image: rigid body doesn't affected by distortion]

Comment: can't you make them part of the cylinder so that they are also affected by the lattice?

Comment: If I do it, they will be squashed. They are rigid, can't be squashed.
They should only rotate following the floor

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way: Select your small cylinder, shift select the big one, go in *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the big one, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

The small should follow:

[image]